# What is our tagging philosophy?

Tags: discussion, tags

Jeff Atwood [says](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), "It is my strong belief that the tags page is **an essential map of what your community is, and is not, about.**"  Many sites have a primary set of tags that categorize questions.  On [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags), those primary tags are the *only* tag most questions carry.  It's easy to see the site is about games.  Looking at [our tags](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags), it's obvious our site is about the texts of the Bible.  So I think our basic tagging scheme is working out.

There are, however *many* secondary tags, including our most popular three: [exegesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis), [translation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), and [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches).  It's much less clear how these are organized.  (Though, in a sense, that's ok: it's a [folksonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy), not a taxonomy.)  [Do we need](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/47/68) [exegesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis)?  How should we [use](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/161/68) [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches)?  Who is going to get [the badge](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/badges/82/translation) for [translation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) next?  (Alternatively, does using [hebrew](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew), [aramaic](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aramaic), or [greek](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) imply a [translation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag?)

How can we organize our secondary tags to make sense?

Comment: Related: Shog9's answer to [“bible” tag too general?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/174/914)